# Sendmail support of empty group addresses (AKA list syntax)

Tags: sendmail, rfc

E-mail group addresses such as `undisclosed-recipients:;` or `a group:<u1@example.net>,<u@x.example.net>;` are valid forms of addressing according to [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322), see for instance the [illustrative example in Appendix A.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#appendix-A.1.3). In Sendmail, this is called "list syntax". Minimal working example (for Bash):

```
echo "Date: $(date --rfc-2822)
From: <someone@example.net>
To: a group:<r1@example.net>,<r2@example.net>;
" | sendmail -t
```

However, trying to submit messages with empty groups leads to error `List:; syntax illegal for recipient addresses`. Minimal example:

```
echo "Date: $(date --rfc-2822)
From: <someone@example.net>
To: undisclosed-recipients:;
Bcc: someone-else@example.net
" | sendmail -t
```

returns

```
undisclosed-recipients:;... List:; syntax illegal for recipient addresses
```

How can Sendmail be configured to support empty RFC 5322 group addresses when submitting messages via `sendmail -t`?

Comment: Why can't you specify recipients via command line?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip I could, it's just not the question here. Moreover, `sendmail -t` is the default for PHP mail() e.g. on *nix systems.

Comment: How would you like `sendmail -t ...` to process such addresses? a) ignore b) expand LOCAL mailing lists/aliases

Comment: If I am not mistaken `foo:;` is an empty group. It should be ignored just like `(foo)` or `" "`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at Sendmail's source code my conclusion is that in order to have Sendmail support (or rather ignore) empty groups properly a change of the source code is required.

Empty group addresses such as `To: foo:;` should simply be ignored just like `To: (foo)` or `To:` or `''` (i.e. nothing). By debugging I found that this is not an issue with `submit.cf`. Cf rules are never applied to empty addresses. In `parseaddr.c`, `parseaddr->prescan` returns NULL for empty addresses, but not for `:;`. This can be shown by submitting messages to `sendmail -t -d20.1`.

Workarounds are:

- Use `(foo)` instead of `foo:;`
- Use "impudent"(*) rewriting + discarding as shown by user **at** in [phpBB: List:; syntax illegal for recipient addresses](https://www.phpbb.de/community/viewtopic.php?p=270579&sid=d567c5177cafe40c8871d0468bb6fe6f#p270579) (archived at 
  https://archive.is/rQJ8X) (code not tested)

(*) quoting the original author